# How to convert float to byte array of length 4 (array of char*)?

Tags: c++

How to convert float to byte array of length 4 (array of char*) ? I need to send over network some data, tcp, and need to send float as a byte array. ( I know precision to two decimal digits, so at the moment I on client side multiply by 100 and on server divide by 100  - basically convert to integer and then find bytes with & 0xff   << operations). But it is ugly and can lost precision during time.

Comment: I think you require 8 bytes to keep precision.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma That's a `double`, in general. On most modern systems, `float` is the 4-byte IEEE-754 format.

Comment: Don't discount endian accounting in your final solution unless you are restricting your client/server to one format (big or small).

Answer (score 18):

Reading *any* type as a sequence of bytes is quite simple:

```
float f = 0.5f;

unsigned char const * p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(&f);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(float); ++i)
{
    std::printf("The byte #%zu is 0x%02X\n", i, p[i]);
}
```

*Writing* to a float from a network stream works similarly, only you'd leave out the `const`.

It is always permitted to reinterpret any object as a sequence of bytes (any `char`-type is permissible), and this expressly *not* an aliasing violation. Note that the binary representation of any type is of course platform dependent, so you should only use this for serialization if the recipient has the same platform.

Comment: But this, of course, doesn't really help him if he has to write bytes to the network.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Sure, you can use `write(fd, p, sizeof(float))`... the question is who can *read* that :-)

Comment: There's practically no case where `write` would be correct.  But the question was to output over the network.  So what he writes must correspond to the format the protocol he's using has defined.

Answer (score 6):

The first thing you have to do is to determine the format of the
float in the network protocol.  Just knowing that it is 4 bytes
doesn't tell you much: IBM mainframe, Oracle Sparc and the usual
PC all have four byte floats, but they have three different
formats.  Once you know the format, depending on it and your
portability requirements, two different strategies can be used:

If the format in the protocol is IEEE (the most frequent case),
and you don't have to be portable to machines which aren't IEEE
(Windows and most Unix are IEEE—most mainframes aren't),
then you can use type punning to convert the float to
a `uint32_t`, and output that, using either:

```
std::ostream&
output32BitUInt( std::ostream& dest, uint32_t value )
{
    dest.put( (value >> 24) & 0xFF );
    dest.put( (value >> 16) & 0xFF );
    dest.put( (value >>  8) & 0xFF );
    dest.put( (value      ) & 0xFF );
}
```

for big-endian (the usual network order), or:

```
std::ostream&
output32BitUInt( std::ostream& dest, uint32_t value )
{
    dest.put( (value      ) & 0xFF );
    dest.put( (value >>  8) & 0xFF );
    dest.put( (value >> 16) & 0xFF );
    dest.put( (value >> 24) & 0xFF );
}
```

for little-endian (used by some protocols).  Which one you use
will depend on the format defined for the protocol.

To convert from `float` to `uint32_t`, you'll have to check your
compiler.  Using `memcpy` is the only method fully guaranteed by
the standard; the intent is that using
a `reinterpret_cast<uint32_t&>` on the float work as well, and
most (all?) compiler also support using a `union`.

If you need to be portable to mainframes as well, or the format
is something other than IEEE, then you'll need to extract
exponent, sign and mantissa from the float, and output each in
the target format.  Something like the following should work to
output IEEE big-endian on *any* machine (including mainframes
which don't use IEEE), and should give you some idea:

```
oxdrstream&
oxdrstream::operator<<(
    float               source )
{
    BytePutter          dest( *this ) ;
    bool                isNeg = source < 0 ;
    if ( isNeg ) {
        source = - source ;
    }
    int                 exp ;
    if ( source == 0.0 ) {
        exp = 0 ;
    } else {
        source = ldexp( frexp( source, &exp ), 24 ) ;
        exp += 126 ;
    }
    uint32_t               mant = source ;
    dest.put( (isNeg ? 0x80 : 0x00) | exp >> 1 ) ;
    dest.put( ((exp << 7) & 0x80) | ((mant >> 16) & 0x7F) ) ;
    dest.put( mant >> 8 ) ;
    dest.put( mant      ) ;
    return *this ;
}
```

(`BytePutter` is a simple class which takes care of the usual
boilerplate and does error checking.)  Of course, the various
manipulations for the output will be different if the output
format is not IEEE, but this should show the basic principles.
(If you need portability to some of the more exotic mainframes,
which don't support `uint32_t`, you can replace it with any
unsigned integral type which is larger than 23 bits.)

Answer (score 6):

Just overlay the data in one area, in C

```
union dataUnion {  
    float f;  
    char fBuff[sizeof(float)];  
}  
// to use:  
dataUnion myUnion;  
//  
myUnion.f = 3.24;  
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(float);i++)  
    fputc(myUnion.fbuff[i],fp); // or what ever stream output....
```