# Directly converting float array to byte array of size 8

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lvalue, reinterpret-cast

The following code adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14018949/1227860) converts `float` to byte array of length 4 (array of `char*`).

```
float f = 0.5f;
unsigned char const * p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(&f);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(float); ++i)
{
    std::printf("The byte #%zu is 0x%02X\n", i, p[i]);
}
```

I am trying to modify it to work with arrays of type double (8-byte double):

```
float arr[3] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f}; 
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
    unsigned char const * p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(&(double)arr[j]);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(double); ++i)
    {
        std::printf("The byte #%zu is 0x%02X\n", i, p[i]);
    }
}
```

However, the Visual Studio 2019 C++ compiler complains about expecting an lvalue for casting to `p`.

```
E0158   expression must be an lvalue or a function designator
C2102   '&' requires l-value
```

So what I did was an additional copying, which I try to avoid.

```
float arr[3] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f}; 
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
    double d = arr[j];
    unsigned char const * p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(&d);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(float); ++i)
    {
        std::printf("The byte #%zu is 0x%02X\n", i, p[i]);
    }
}
```

Is there any direct way of casting the elements of `arr` without copying?

Comment: Did you ask this earlier today?  I've seen this _exact_ question only an hour or two ago, except this time you're attempting to do `&(double)arr[j]` instead of `&arr[j]` which is clearly a bad thing, as pointed out by the compiler.

Comment: Yes, I posted the wrong question. How would you approach byte arrays of size 64 bits?

Comment: You cannot take the address of the temporary that is a result of a conversion cast from float to double.  If you need a double, you need to store it.  The compiler can optimize that as best it can, but it'll still probably need to go on the stack.  You don't have an option here.  The way you're doing it successfully, storing the result in `d` is just fine.  If you're somehow concerned about performance, consider that the conversion from float to double is most likely slower than or similar to storing the result in memory, and the store is hundreds of times slower than the `printf` call.